# How to avoid calling onComplete before on next is finished?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Let's say I have a data service class that fetches the data batch by batch and its chunks to the subscribers.

```
public class DataService {
   public IObservable<IList<T>> QuerySegmentedObservable<T>(string tableName)  where T : TableEntity, new(){

       return Observable.Create<IList<T>>(async (observer, token) =>{
           TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
           do{
               var currentSegment = CallData();
               observer.OnNext(currentSegment.Results);

               continuationToken = currentSegment.ContinuationToken;
           } while (continuationToken != null);
           observer.OnCompleted();
       } 
   }
 }
```

I am subscribing this observable as below.

```
 public async Task<bool> MyMethod()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            var observable = _dataService.QuerySegmentedObservable<TSource>(_sourceTableName);

            var dataCount = 0;

             _databaseService.OpenConnection();

            observable.Subscribe(async data =>
            {                
                await _databaseService.DoSomething(data);

                dataCount += data.Count;

                Console.WriteLine($"Processing - {dataCount}");
            },
            err =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error - {err.Message}");
                tcs.SetResult(false);
            },
            () =>
            {    
                _databaseService.CloseConnection();
                Console.WriteLine($"Finished");
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
            );

            return await tcs.Task;
        }
```

The problem is that OnComplete() is called before the last OnNext() is finished. So, I ended up closing the connection before finishing the task that I am doing in Subscribe();

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing asynchronous operations from the `onNext` block.

Comment: What is the type of `_databaseService`?

Comment: @En It's just a class that inserts the data to database or do something that might take a couple of seconds up to 40 seconds.

Comment: @ redent84 I thought new version of rx supports async/await, no?

Answer (score 0):

Rx does support async/await within operators. You're using it though within a subscription. So (hopefully) you can change your code to something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> MyMethod()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    _databaseService.OpenConnection();
    var dataCount = 0;
    _dataService.QuerySegmentedObservable<TSource>(_sourceTableName)
        .SelectMany(async data =>
        {
            await _databaseService.DoSomething(data);
            return data;
        })
        //.Finally(() => _databaseService.CloseConnection()) //This would be called on OnComplete and OnError, just like try-finally
        .Subscribe(data =>
            {
                dataCount += data.Count;

                Console.WriteLine($"Processing - {dataCount}");
            },
            err =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error - {err.Message}");
                tcs.SetResult(false);
            },
            () =>
            {
                _databaseService.CloseConnection(); //Maybe move this to a Finally call?
                Console.WriteLine($"Finished");
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
        );

    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

I can't really test it, so I hope that sets you on the right path. If you need more help, then please post a better [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).